# Datepicker minDate with StartDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

What I am trying to do with datepicker is when it first shows, display the current date plus 6 months, which you can do with startDate, but the month back button is disabled. I tried to set a minDate for todays date, same deal, month back button is disabled.

Is there away to have the start date to be the current date plus 6 months, but allow users to click the month back button and not allowed to go past the current date.

```
var date = new Date();
                date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
                var defaultDate = new Date();
                defaultDate.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);

                $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
                        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                        autoHide: true,
                        minDate: date,
                        startDate: defaultDate,
                        changeMonth: true
                });
```

Comment: Which datepicker plugin do you use?

Comment: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To accomplish what you want you just need to set:

`startDate`: with the current date, so users will not be allowed to go past this date. [[docs reference for startDate]](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/blob/master/README.md#startdate)

AND

`date`: with the date that you want to show as default in the datepicker. [[docs reference for date]](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/blob/master/README.md#date)

Also looks like the datepicker plugin that you are using doesn't have these 2 properties: `minDate` and `changeMonth`. So there's no need to use it here.

```
 var date = new Date();
 
 date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
 var defaultDate = new Date();
 defaultDate.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);

 $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
  autoHide: true,
  date: defaultDate,
  startDate: date,
 });
```

You can check all options for this plugin [here](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/blob/master/README.md#startdate).

Also, you can simulate it [here](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/)

Answer (score 5):

You have to set startDate to today and date to today +6 month

```
var date = new Date();
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
            var defaultDate = new Date();
            defaultDate.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);

            $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                    autoHide: true,
                    minDate: date,
                    startDate: date,
                    date: defaultDate,
                    changeMonth: true
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### We have properties

```
minDate -> For setting minimum selectable date
startDate -> For setting onload selected date
maxDate -> For setting maximum selectable date
```

#### We also have a similar function

```
setMinDate
setStartDate
setEndDate -> if its datepicker-range
setMaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
     date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
     var dt = new Date();
     dt.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);

jQuery('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    autoHide: true,
    minDate: date,
    startDate: date,
    date: dt,
    changeMonth: true
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from answering questions with just a code snippet. [Check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write an answer.